# In a Hibernate SQL query how do you escape ? character in the field name

Tags: sql, sql-server, hibernate, escaping, illegal-characters

This is a SQL Server DB and the developer, many years ago, made a column name for boolean values contain a `?` character.  Many systems access this DB, so changing this column name isn't really an option for me.

This works in native MS tools:

```
SELECT * FROM MyDatabase.dbo.[My Table] WHERE [Active?]= true
```

That same query fails in a `session.createSQLQuery` with Hibernate throwing an error attempting to interpret the `?` inside the bracketed field name as a parameter.

I've tried backticks [`Active?\`]

I've tried escaping with /! [Active/!?] and vice versa !/ [Active!/?] with no effect.

I've also looked around quite a few stack overflow and web forums for other suggestions but the other things I've tried have not worked.

Is this a bug in hibernate?  It seems to me that nothing in brackets should be interpretable as parameters.

The specific error is a query exception

```
> Expected positional parameter count: 1, actual parameters:[]
```

with the query string attached.

**[joachim-isaksson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/477878/joachim-isaksson) Answered it: `[Active\\?]` is it**

Comment: What does the mapping for `Active?` look like?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, not sure what you mean by mapping.  This isn't an hql mapping.  I do have a class that maps to the table that I will probably need to modify as well but the error is occurring in the code before I actually get to assign myObject = query.list();

Comment: Ah, missed the `createSQLQuery` part. I'd take a wild stab at `[Active\\?]` (ie one backslash should be passed to hibernate, just doubled since otherwise Java will remove it), but I don't currently have a setup to test on.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, that was it.  I could've sworn I tried that and got errors in the string.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

@[joachim-isaksson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/477878/joachim-isaksson) Answered it `[Active\\?]`

Answer (score 5):

To replicate this use case, I created the [`SQLServerEscapeQuestionCharacterTest`](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/high-performance-java-persistence/blob/master/core/src/test/java/com/vladmihalcea/book/hpjp/hibernate/query/escape/SQLServerEscapeQuestionCharacterTest.java) in my [`high-performance-java-persistence` GitHub repository](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/high-performance-java-persistence).

Assuming you have the following JPA entity:

```
@Entity(name = "Post")
@Table(name = "[post]")
public static class Post {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String title;

    @Column(name = "[active?]")
    private boolean active;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }
}
```

Which is associated with the following database table:

```
CREATE TABLE [post] (
    id bigint not null, 
    [active?] bit, 
    title varchar(255), 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

If you create the following `Post` entity:

```
Post post = new Post();
post.setId(1L);
post.setTitle("High-Performance Java Persistence");
post.setActive(true);

entityManager.persist(post);
```

Hibernate will execute the proper INSERT statement:

```
INSERT INTO [post] (
    [active?], 
    title, 
    id
) 
VALUES (
    true, 
    'High-Performance Java Persistence', 
    1
)
```

When executing a JPQL query:

```
List<Post> posts = entityManager
.createQuery(
    "select p " +
    "from Post p " +
    "where p.active = :active", Post.class)
.setParameter("active", true)
.getResultList();

assertEquals(1, posts.size());
```

Hibernate uses the `name` attribute of the JPA `@Column` which already escapes the column name:

```
SELECT p.id AS id1_0_,
       p.[active?] AS active2_0_,
       p.title AS title3_0_
FROM [post] p
WHERE p.[active?] = true
```

For native SQL queries, you need to escape the `?` character like this:

```
List<String> posts = entityManager
.createNativeQuery(
    "select p.title " +
    "from [post] p " +
    "where p.[active\\?] = :active")
.setParameter("active", true)
.getResultList();

assertEquals(1, posts.size());
```

And, it works like a charm.